# Plotting a polar curve

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

The question is, to generate a polar graph using a graphing utility, and to choose parameter interval so that the complete graph is generated.

$$r=\cos\frac{\theta}{5}$$

To find such an interval, we are looking for smallest number of complete revolutions until value of $r$ begins to repeat. Algebraically,this amounts to

$$\cos\frac{\theta}{5}=\cos\frac{\theta+2n\pi}{5}$$

For this equality to hold,$\frac{2n\pi}{5}$ must be an even multiple of $\pi$,the smallest n for which it occurs is $n=5$.Therefore, the graph will be traced completely in $5$ revolutions ($10\pi$).

But when I draw it the graph is completely traced in $5\pi$, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Try graphing $r=cos\theta$ by hand. It creates a circle between 0 and $\pi$. It re-traces the same circle between $\pi$ and $2\pi$.  The same thing occurs in your graph.

Comment: @PaulSundheim how is that same with this graph, this graph does not trace itself before $5\pi$, and i am getting $10\pi$.

Comment: As you said, "the graph is completely traced in 5π" but now you say "this graph does not trace itself before 5π"? Which is the correct statement?

Comment: I just traced it on a graphing calculator.  Seemed to be complete in $5\pi$ and then repeated.

Comment: @PaulSundheim The graph is completely traced in 5pi means after that you are just tracing it again.I know 5pi is correct, do you mind telling where is the computation wrong?

Comment: There is no error in the computation. Half of the $10\pi$ interval the curve has positive radius and half with negative radius.  This causes the curve to "double back" on itself.

Comment: @PaulSundheim thanks for clearing that, but how will i know that. SIDENOTE: while doing this i got that if you are plotting $\cos\pi/n$, if n is even the graph will be completely traced in $2n\pi$ and if it is odd then it will be traced in $n\pi$. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$r(5\pi+t)=\cos(\pi+\frac{t}5)=-\cos(\frac{t}{5})=-r(t)$.  Also the angle at $5\pi+t$ points in the opposite direction of the angle at $t$.  Hence you get repetition.

Comment: $r(5\pi+t)=$?? what do you mean.

Comment: He means $r$ evaluated at $5\pi+t$

Comment: got it thanks for the help.

Comment: @Paul S.  Yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Since the question has been already answered, I post here a *visual answer* that I hope may help you to understand the problem better:

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: very helpful and cool, which utility is this.

Comment: Hi @Shobhit. This was entirely done with Matlab.